# How to optimistically update the database when a form value changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this callback function that is called from a child component that updates the form (I'm using `react-hook-form`) of the parent component

```
  const goalSetter = useMemo(() => {
    return (value: string[]) => {
      const goals: Goals[] = value
        .map((goal) => stringToEnumValue(goal, Goals))
        .filter((v) => !!v) as Goals[];

      form.setValue('goals', [...goals]);
      await updateUserData('goals');
    };
  }, []);
```

Problem is the `updateUserData` function takes a long time to execute and slows down the app. So, it takes about a second to see the visual feedback in the UI.

updateUserData:

```
  const updateUserData = async (field: ProfileField) => {
    await form.trigger(field);
    if (form.formState.isValid) {
      await updateUser(userDataSchema.cast(form.getValues()));
    } else {
      form.setError(field, {
        type: 'validation-error',
        message: 'Please enter a valid input',
      });
      console.log('form is not valid');
    }
  };
```

I have tried memoizing the functions but that barely makes a difference. How can I refactor this to do the update part in the background and increase the responsiveness ?

Any help is welcome. Thanks